# CSS anchor tag and class calling at the same time

Tags: css

```css
a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#666;
 border-left:2px solid grey;
 padding-left:10px;
}
li{
 display:inline;
 margin-left:10px;
 color:grey;
}
```

i have written this code in "style tag" but the same code is applying on all links, i aslo made separate divs and classes and please tell me some way to use this code for different classes with different value like in one links div i want that code, but in other links div i don't want the border left and color= grey,,,but if i chnage it then the change will also occur at other places please tell me something better?

Comment: Sorry kiddo, but you sound like you need to learn CSS from the start.

Comment: I dont understand exactly your question, but why dont go and start reading https://www.washington.edu/accesscomputing/webd2/student/unit3/module5/lesson1.html about `classes` and `id` maybe will clarify what are you asking

Comment: ok sir that doesn't matter, thanks for your time and yes i'll try some other sources to get that answer of this question.